# Integration open source with Sentry

Tags: spring-boot, dockerfile, monitoring, logback, sentry

I need to integrate with sentry for monitoring open source exceptions, I am only allowed to use image of the open source, it is an spring boot application, I am trying to add sentry Logback jar file to the open source image but it is not working and I am not sure if this is the correct way

```
FROM opensource:latest
ADD jar-file/ /var/opensource/external-jar-files/
RUN java -cp /var/opensource/external-jar-files/sentry-logback.jar com.getsentry.raven
```

this Dockerfiles give me an error when I am running the container **no main manifest attribute, in /var/opensource/external-jar-files/sentry-logback.jar**

maybe this isn't the way, any advice?

Comment: follow the docs https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/ it should be pretty much straightforward.
com.getsentry.raven is an old version, be sure to use the latest one to take all the spring boot advantages.

Comment: @ManoelNeto thank you for your response, my idea is to take the jar file and put it in the external jars file in the container, the document will help when I can add the dependency to the open source project but unfortunately I couldn't. I am looking for writing custom dockerFile to do such a case